# Dimension of Tensor Product for Flat Extensions

Tags: commutative-algebra

Suppose that $A,B,$ and $C$ are commutative unital rings, $A\to B$ is flat, and $A\to C$ is any map.  I am trying to determine whether 
$$
\dim B\otimes_AC=\dim B+\dim C-\dim A
$$
Any counterexamples or references?  I am taking the Krull dimension of the zero ring to be -1 (in case a tensor product is 0).

Thanks for any feedback.

Edit: By $\dim$ I mean Krull dimension.

Comment: can one add assumptions like "finite"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $A=k,$ a field and $B=k(x), C=k(y)$ where $x,y$ are transcendental over $k.$ Then the ring $k(x)\otimes_kk(y)$ is an one dimensional ring (Qing Liu, Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves, Ch. 3, Ex. 1.9) and this clearly contradicts the stated equality.

Answer (score 4):

Take $A=\mathbb Z,$ and $B=C=\mathbb Q$. Then $B\otimes_AC=\mathbb Q$ and your formula gives: $0=0+0-1$, absurd.

Comment: This is a far better example than the one I gave. Very nice and elementary.